# Validate indexed(non associative) array size

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

For indexed array content that would work:

```
'*.moo' => 'bail|required|string',
```

How to validate the array itself so that the array size does not exceed the max value?

```
'????' => 'max:10'
```

Comment: Exactly what kind of validations are you willing to do? I can see `string` and `required` with `max:10`. What is `bail`?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `$request->json()` array size

Comment: Could you be more specific because you also have `max:10`?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat exactly I want my array size not to exceed 10 length

Comment: 1. max: 10    2. isRequired: yes    3: must be string      4. total array size should not be more than 10? Sounds good?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat if you tell me how **total array size should not be more than 10** it's more than enough

Comment: http://developed.be/2015/03/05/laravel-form-array-validation-array_size-required_if/ can you try if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put array validation as well, because this is how laravel validator deducts field type

```
[
    'field' => 'required|array|max:10',
]
```